Sitecore Content Search API not giving results on more than 3 words search string
We are facing some weird issue where passing the same predicate in lower environments to content search GetQueryable method is yielding results, but results are not showing in higher environments.
In higher environments, if the predicate is:

More than 3 keywords, no results are showing
Less than 3 keywords, we are getting results

Though this is working fine in lower environments like on my local machine, I am looking for any settings from configuration which would cause this issue in a higher environment.
I tried to compare the configuration files but found things identical on files likes content search configuration.
I am looking for some specific settings which I may be missing here.
Any help will be appreciated!

Can you confirm solr setup is the sMe between environments? Is it on prem or cloud? Also are indexes similar sized? Suggest pulling the solr query from search logs and running direct on solr dashboard

The only setting that may be limiting your query size is requestHeaderSize https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0191459. It's difficult to say more without seeing your actual Solr query. Also, is your content identical on the local machine and higher environments?
